# Jumbling up an image

Tags: php, image, image-manipulation

So I want to be able to jumble up an image so as to distort the original image. What I mean is this. Load an image, loop through the image and take 32x32 blocks and store each individual block in an array. Then reassemble them as a new picture with the blocks in random order.

this is the code I have currently to take and store the blocks from original image and then create reassemble the image (Note this doesn't have the randomization part yet). But for some reason it doesn't output correctly.

```
<?php

$name = "pic.jpg";

$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($name);
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($name);

$x_size = floor($width/32);
$y_size = floor($height/32);

$mixed = array();

$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor(32,32);

$x = 0;
$y = 0;

for($y = 0; $y < $height; $y+= 32) {
    for($x = 0; $x < $width; $x+=32) {
        imagecopy($new_image, $src, 0, 0, $x, $y, 32, 32); 
        array_push($mixed, $new_image);
    }
}

$final_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

$i = 0;
$x1 = 0;
$y1 = 0;

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($mixed); $i++) {

    $x1++;

    if($x1 >= $x_size) {
        $x1 = 0;
        $y1++;
    }

    imagecopymerge($final_image, $mixed[$i], $x1, $y1, 0,0,32,32,100); 
}

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($final_image);

?>
```

Original Image:

http://puu.sh/236XS

Output:

http://puu.sh/236YO

If you can help it wouldbe greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but the photo makes it very hard to read your question...

Comment: Updated OP to lessen the boners :)

Comment: @j08691 Please I'm still at work ahahah

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own question using the following code:

```
<?php
include("test.php");
//global variables
$name = "pic.jpg";
$size = 64;
$x = 0;
$y = 0;

$spots = array("0,0", "0,1", "0,2", "0,3",
               "1,0", "1,1", "1,2", "1,3",
               "2,0", "2,1", "2,2", "2,3",
               "3,0", "3,1", "3,2", "3,3");

//open image from file (Original image)
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($name);
//load image details
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($name);

//calculate amount of tiles on x/y axis.
$x_size = floor($width/$size);
$y_size = floor($height/$size);

$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($size,$size);
$final_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$used = array();

for($y = 0; $y < $height; $y+= $size) {
    for($x = 0; $x < $width; $x+= $size) {

            //generate random x/y coordinates
            redo:
            $spot = rand(0, sizeof($spots)-1);

            if(!in_array($spot, $used)) {
                $coords = explode(",", $spots[$spot]);

                //grab 32x32 square from original image
                imagecopy($new_image, $src, 0, 0, $x, $y, $size, $size); 
                //place 32x32 square into new image at randomly generated coordinates
                imagecopy($final_image, $new_image, $coords[0]*$size, $coords[1]*$size, 0,0,$size,$size); 
                array_push($used, $spot);

            } else {
                goto redo;
            }

    }
}

//display final image

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($final_image);

print_r($used);
?>
```

Might not be the most efficient code, but it works :)